# Forever repeat of an eventloop after each loop completion, in python 3.4

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

I am using python 3.4.
I'm trying to have a loop of several tasks running asynchronously and when one circle of loop was complete then again loop starts from beginning. It is necessary to start the loop again only after the last round was complete. I thought this code might be what I'm looking for but it only runs once.

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def some_task(name, number):
    print('task ', name, ' started')
    yield from asyncio.sleep(number)
    print('task ', name, ' finished')

@asyncio.coroutine
def loop_executer(loop, tasks):
    if not loop.is_running():
        loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(tasks))

tasks = [
    asyncio.ensure_future(some_task("A", 2)),
    asyncio.ensure_future(some_task("B", 5)),
    asyncio.ensure_future(some_task("C", 4))]

ev_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ev_loop.create_task(loop_executer(ev_loop, tasks))
ev_loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Why is `loop_executer` calling `run_until_complete` while you're also calling `run_forever`?

Comment: @AndrewCheong, because I need three tasks to be completed before new loop starts again.

Comment: Why exactly do you even care about *“a new loop”*? The point of an event loop is to run forever and to react to events within the loop. There is no *completion* or *new start* in an event loop. When it runs, it runs.

Comment: (Not to mention that `run_until_complete` also runs *the same* event loop possibly a few hundred times already)

Comment: @poke, I think `run_until_complete` runs the loop only once and what you say is done if there is an internal loop in the tasks. Is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes, an [event loop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_loop) runs repeatedly and on every iteration it checks for an event and handles it, or does nothing. It runs very quickly and does very little things on every iteration to ensure a maximum responsiveness. So yes, it’s very likely that the loop runs *a lot* while it waits for your tasks to finish, only to start (or rather continue) the outer “forever loop” then. – But what exactly are you trying to accomplish with your code? Do you want to run those three tasks repeatedly (but only once they are all done), or what?

Comment: @poke, yes exactly, I'm trying to run tasks repeatedly but each repeat is only after all tasks are done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no mechanism to repeat tasks - wrap  it `while` loop.

```
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def some_task(name, number):
    print('task ', name, ' started')
    yield from asyncio.sleep(number)
    print('task ', name, ' finished')

@asyncio.coroutine
def loop_executer(loop):
    # you could use even while True here
    while loop.is_running():
        tasks = [
            some_task("A", 2),
            some_task("B", 5),
            some_task("C", 4)
        ]
        yield from asyncio.wait(tasks)

ev_loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
ev_loop.create_task(loop_executer(ev_loop))
ev_loop.run_forever()
```

You don't have to use `ensure_future` on coroutines.

Comment: decorator @coroutine is deprecated, how to use `async def` instead?